# What is the pickling problem that persistent IDs are used to solve here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#persistence-of-external-objects

> For the beneﬁt of object persistence, the pickle module supports the
>   **notion of a reference to an object outside the pickled data stream**.
>   Such objects are referenced by a persistent ID, which should be either
>   a string of alphanumeric characters (for protocol 0) or just an
>   arbitrary object (for any newer protocol).

I'd appreciate if someone could explain: what is the pickling problem that persistent IDs are used to solve here? In other words, what problem will pickling have if not using persistent IDs?

In particular, what does "notion of a reference to an object outside the pickled data stream" mean? Is it opposed to some other notion such as "notion of a reference to an object inside the pickled data stream"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A “pickle data stream” is the generic description of “what `pickle.dump` and `pickle.load` do”. A *data stream* is for example a file to and from which data can be read *sequentially*. It is a *pickle data* stream when said stream contains *data produced or consumed by pickle*.

Pickle streams have a notion of *internal references* - if the same object occurs multiple times in a stream, it is stored only once and then just referenced. However, this only refers to what is already stored in the stream - a reference cannot point to an object outside the stream, such as the original object. The content of a pickle data stream is conceptually a copy of its original data.

```
import pickle

bar = (1, 2)
foo = {1: 1, 2: (1, 1), 'bar': bar}

with open('foo.pkl', 'wb') as out_stream:  # open a data stream...
     pickle.dump((bar, foo), out_stream)   # ...for pickle data

with open('foo.pkl', 'rb') as in_stream:
     bar2, foo2 = pickle.load(in_stream)

assert bar2 is foo2['bar']  # internal identity is preserved
assert bar is not bar2      # external identity is broken
```

A persistent ID can be used to refer to something not in the stream - such as the original object, or a global database handle, or something in another stream, or similar. Conceptually, persistent IDs simply allow other code to handle pickling/unpickling. The definition and implementation of persistent IDs depend on the problem to solve, however.

Defining and using persistent IDs is not difficult. However, it requires some orchestration and bookkeeping. A very simple example looks like this:

```
import pickle

# some object to persist
# usually, one would have some store or bookkeeping in place
bar = (1, 2)


# The create/load implementation of the persistent id
# extends pickling/unpickling
class PersistentPickler(pickle.Pickler):
    def persistent_id(self, obj):
        """Return a persistent id for the `bar` object only"""
        return "it's a bar" if obj is bar else None


class PersistentUnpickler(pickle.Unpickler):
    def persistent_load(self, pers_id):
        """Return the object identified by the persistent id"""
        if pers_id == "it's a bar":
           return bar
        raise pickle.UnpicklingError("This is just an example for one persistent object!")


# we can now dump and load the persistent object
foo = {'bar': bar}
with open("foo.pkl", "wb") as out_stream:
    PersistentPickler(out_stream).dump(foo)

with open("foo.pkl", "rb") as in_stream:
    foo2 = PersistentUnpickler(in_stream).load()

assert foo2 is not foo     # regular objects are not persistent
assert foo2['bar'] is bar  # persistent object identity is preserved
```

---

As a real-world example, my old [cpy2py module](https://github.com/maxfischer2781/cpy2py) uses pickle to exchange data between different interpreters. For regular value-like objects, this means serialising in one interpreter and deserialising in another. For some special stateful objects, this means exchanging only a persistent ID that uniquely identifies the object across all connected interpreters.

There is some bookkeeping involved, but you can think of the [persistent ID](https://github.com/maxfischer2781/cpy2py/blob/master/cpy2py/proxy/tracker.py) in this case as the tuple `(process_id, object_id, object_type)`. The owning interpreter can use this ID to look up the real object, while other interpreters can create a placeholder object instead. The entire point in this case is that the state is not stored and replicated, but merely referenced.